# How to know a meteor app is started for the first time?

Tags: ios, meteor

I'd like to prominently show a 'help' button when my meteor app is opened for the first time (on iOS). What's the best way to achieve this? That is, how can I easily confirm my meteor app is opened for the first time, after installing the app on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

set a NSUserDefaults parameter called helpShown, check setting to know which display controller to display. set to true when help is clicked / dismissed

Comment: This is within Xcode, no? I was hoping for a solution that I could implement within my Meteor app.

Comment: No he's saying that when a user creates an account, add a key value to their user keys that is called "helpShown" : true. When that is set to true, show your help button via a helper in blaze. When the use clicks it, update their user key of "helpShow" to false.

Comment: Ah, I see. That works if I force users to log in. Not if I allow guest access as well.

Comment: OK I understood better your question .. lacking context. Meteor is a JavaScript language than run on ios... Solution remain the same. Store the condition of showing a given screen to user settings.  I dunnot know java but I guess similar functions are there to encapsulate user settings in their API.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// set here a bool value
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"showHelp"];
//...............
return YES;
```

}

//somewhere you add your help button

//......

//remove/hide help button

```
- (void)helpFinishAction:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"showHelp"]) {
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"showHelp"];
    NSLog(@"remove/hide you help button here");
    //remove/hide you help button here
}
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution within Meteor, yeah?